# Checkboxes checked when value IN comma separated string (or array) Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

How would I change this JS function to only check the checkboxes with a value in a comma separated string? With MySQL I can do this using the "IN" function, is there a function like that in Javascript? Cannot seem to find..

I want to select a "Group" Checkbox with a value of 1,2,3,4,5...... and when checked, check the "individual" checkbox below with a single value of 1....or...2....or....3....etc.

Example:

(Checkbox 1) Group 1  Value="1,2,3"

(Checkbox 2) Item 1 Value="1"

(Checkbox 3) Item 2 Value="2"

(Checkbox 4) Item 3 Value="3"

(Checkbox 5) Item 4 Value="4"

So if checkbox 1 is checked, checkboxes 2,3,4 would be checked.

```
function SetAllCheckBoxes(FormName, FieldName, CheckValue) {
    if (!document.forms[FormName]) return;

    var objCheckBoxes = document.forms[FormName].elements[FieldName];  
    if (!objCheckBoxes) return;

    var countCheckBoxes = objCheckBoxes.length;
    if (!countCheckBoxes) {
        objCheckBoxes.checked = CheckValue;
    }
    else {
        // set the check value for all check boxes
        for(var i = 0; i < countCheckBoxes; i++) {
            objCheckBoxes[i].checked = CheckValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with new line characters?!

Comment: I absolutely LOVE horizontal scrolling :D

Comment: @user1071915: In the future, please format your code to make it easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, updated my question based on the cryptic nature of this question.  So you want to see whether an object has a value which exists in a comma-delimited string?  If so:

```
function SetAllCheckBoxes(individualCheckbox,values) {
   if(!individualCheckbox||!values) {
      return; 
   } else {
     var array = values.split(',');  
     for(var i = 0; i <= array.count(); i++) {
        if(individualCheckbox.value == array[i]) {
           return true;
        } 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to check a "group" checkbox with a value of 1,2,3,4.....And have it check the "individual" checkbox that matches below ...1....2.....3.

Comment: What do you mean by a "group" checkbox? And what do you mean "select" the element? You mean you want the function to return it or select it with `focus`?

Answer (score 0):

1) OMG, use braces.

2) What is this about:

```
if(!countCheckBoxes)
    objCheckBoxes.checked = CheckValue;
```

... if you don't have any checkboxes, why are you setting an empty array to CheckValue?

3) You're getting 1 form in the page, and then looking for elements with a particular name within that form.  Do you really ever expect to get more than 1 checkbox? If so, you're html is broken.  Are you talking about a group of radio buttons??

4) Your question isn't clear.  But the answer might be something to do with string function, split:

```
var vals = "a,b,c".split(","); // vals == ["a", "b", "c"]
```

OK, so based upon clarifying the question, I believe the following is what you would need:

```
function SetAllCheckBoxes(FormName, FieldNames, CheckValue) {
    var form = document.forms[FormName];
    if (!form) {
        return;
    }

    var checkboxNames = FieldNames.split(",");
    for (var i=0, l=checkboxNames.length; i<l; i++) {
        var checkboxName = checkboxNames[i].trim(); // needed if your comma separated string may contain spaces
        var checkbox = form.elements[checkboxName];
        checkbox.checked = CheckValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of javascript library? This would be pretty easy in jQuery.

Comment: Im not, for some reason I have trouble with it in Joomla 1.6.....Trying to stick with basic JS

Comment: Tried it, getting a checkbox is undefined....my individual checkbox names are an array "teamarray2[]" should my group checkbox be named differently?

Comment: Dude, it totally works: http://jsfiddle.net/3nNHb/
If you click the first of the 4 checkboxes, it sets the check value to true for the other 3